# High RAM usage during Postgres PITR

Tags: postgresql, recovery, postgresql-10, write-ahead-logging, barman

We're currently running Postgres 10 in our infrastructure with Barman managing weekly full backups and holding onto the WALs. Because of the size of our DB, the WAL volume, and resource constraints when we need to restore and scrub a copy into non-prod it's cheaper to restore it to a staging server with reduced resources, and then clone the datadir to the actual non-prod nodes.

However, with the increase in WAL traffic over time, recently if I can't convince the requestor to go with a PITR close to the weekly full the restore process will consume a massive amount of RAM, dipping into swap, and becoming insufferably slow. Restarting it in the middle seems to reset this trend, mucking up any automation, but I'm wondering if there's a reason for this behavior or a way to address it.

Comment: If the RAM is indeed growing, that would be a PostgreSQL bug you should report. But that would require more details, like the exact version you are using.

Comment: Which process is using the RAM?  Is it the postgreSQL start-up process, or some barman process, or are you just seeing RAM being used by the OS to cache file system data?

Comment: please put output of `show shared_preload_libraries` also

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe we are currently running 10.8

Comment: @jjanes It's the Postgres startup/recovery process. The OS lists the memory usage as cache, but the more granular vmstat metrics show that it's all shared memory.

Comment: @SahapAsci our non-prod envs use only pg_cron, prod addionally uses repmgr and pg_stat_statements.

Comment: I didn't know vmstat could give you shared memory info.  Is it susceptible to double counting the same way other shared memory accounting is?  Can attach the startup backend with the debugger and get a memory usage report? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#Examining_backend_memory_use

Comment: @jjanes I'm looking back at metrics collected with Prometheus' node_exporter, it seems to collect 28 different flavors of memory metrics from different sources. All the different sources have various levels of conflict with each other, and none seem to really agree between sources or want to 'roll up' into numbers that agree with the others. That said, looking at the memory stats for other non-prod PG VMs shows that they all seem to be using a little over 16GB of shared memory, to say nothing of RSS, which I suppose would explain why this VM with only 16GB went so hard into swap.